# REST not working with IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: rest, jax-rs, websphere, restful-architecture

I am using WAS 8.5,RAD

I have developed a rest application it has ibm-wink-jaxrs.jar in its lib .

this is the error-

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[JAX-RS Servlet]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:105)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterByProduces(ResourceRegistry.java:573)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterDispatchMethods(ResourceRegistry.java:497)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.findSubResourceMethod(ResourceRegistry.java:391)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:168)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode.ContentEncodingResponseFilter.doFilter(ContentEncodingResponseFilter.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:947)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

When i removed the ibm-wink-jaxrs.jar from lib of my project 
this is the error i am getting

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[JAX-RS Servlet]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode.ContentEncodingResponseFilter
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:263)
at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:88)
at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:123)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:219)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:89)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:572)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:514)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:319)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:392)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3980)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

This is the web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>projectREST</display-name>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.ajaxproxy.servlet.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
            <description>
            JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
            <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                    <param-value>com.test.service.common.config.RESTApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/proxy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
            <filter-name>ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode.ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

and here is the list of jar files available in lib of my project

```
    AjaxProxy.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
datedFileAppender-1.0.2.jar
IBANUtility.jar
itext-1.3.1.jar
jackson-core-asl.jar
jackson-jaxrs.jar
jackson-mapper-asl.jar
jackson-xc.jar
jasperreports-3.0.0.jar
java-jwt.jar
jsr311-api.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
ServiceConsumer.jar
slf4j-api.jar
ibm-wink-jaxrs
slf4j-jdk14.jar
```

Can any one suggest how to resolve this ,i tried with removing IBM jar but no luck yet .
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the jsr311-api.jar too (in addition to the ivm-wink-jaxrs jar).  The problem is most likely: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI27070

This happens when user applications package their own versions of JAX-RS.  Although the text of the APAR mentions that the conflict is specifically with Jersey, I have found that any JAX-RS implementation can cause the conflict - even a copy of the Wink implementation that is provided with WAS.

It doesn't seem like there is any reason to package IBM's Wink in the application since it is available in the application server already.  Some users will package new versions of JAX-RS implementations (like CXF or Jersey) to get newer APIs than what WAS 8.5 provides, but then that usually requires classloader tricks like parent_last delegation which makes things more complicated.  My recommendation would be to use IBM's JAX-RS implementation (Wink) that ships with WAS.

Note that if you have other applications in the same server that also contain different implementations, those applications could conflict with this one - unless you've applied the patch in the link I mentioned - you may also need to ensure that each of those applications contain the appropriate JAX-RS API jar (i.e. the jsr311 jar).

Hope this helps, Andy

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I am using ibm-wink-jaxrs.jar because of this -<filter>
            <filter-name>ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode.ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>ContentEncodingResponseFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>         available in my web.xml else i am getting class not found for this -ContentEncodingResponseFilter

Comment: when i remove jsr311,ibmwink and that filter line mentioned in above comment it is working fine. but i need that filter in my web.xml

Comment: It sounds like WAS may be preventing classloader access to this "internal" class/package.  You could try opening a PMR to see if this could be unblocked.  

You might also be able to work around this by just taking the source code from org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode.ContentEncodingResponseFilter
and re-packaging it (i.e. `package com.mycompany.org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.contentencode;`) and then put it in your application.  That might be enough on its own, or you may also need to pull in org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.AcceptEncoding too.

Comment: Thanks Andy -As of now i removed this filter from web.xml and removed the jsr.jar and IBM-wink.jar and changed JRE library to was8.5  now it is working in my local but when i am deploying it to QA it is giving same error,QA was has same version as local i.e-was 8.5.5.11.

Comment: Which error?  The NullPointerException?  If so, do you have other applications in the same server?  IIRC, that NPE can occur even if other apps contain a JAX-RS implementation.

Is it possible for you to upgrade to traditional WAS 9.0? Or WebSphere Liberty?  Both of those servers offer JAX-RS 2.0 and more options for resolving this issue.